# How would I send a discord embed with JS?

Tags: javascript, discord, frontend, embed

Currently, I know how to send a normal message with JS, as the code shows below. But how could I turn it into an embed? (front-end)

```
const url = '*********************************************************************************'
    const msg = {
        "content": `this is a discord webhook message`
    }

    fetch(url, {
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": { "content-type": "application/json" },
        "body": JSON.stringify(msg)
    })
```

I tried searching, but found nothing in match to my inquiry.

Comment: Can we get more information, are you sending the message using a bot or a webhook, are you using discord.js or vanilla js to send a message, do you want to attach a file to the embed or no.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation!

I assume, because of your `content`, that you are executing a webhook. So let's look at the documentation as to what may be provided for executing a webhook (creating a normal message is the same in this scenario): https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook

The table has `content` in it just like you have as well as what you're after: `embeds`. It says it's an array of up to 10 embed objects. All you do now is visit the hyperlink to find out what you're able to use in an embed object and pass it as an array.

For example, `{ description: "test" }` is a valid embed object. Put that in an array and place it alongside your `content` (or omit it) with the key `embeds`.